# When launching `screen`, "normal" bash environment isn't setup

Tags: bash

My typical login looks like this:

[image: normal login]

But when I start `screen`, I get just a bare bash environment - no environment variables, aliases, etc:

[image: <code>screen</code> has default bash prompt]

Why is that happening, and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was pointed to `/etc/screenrc` by a friend. It doesn't exist on macOS.

So I copied a working `/etc/screenrc` to `.screenrc` and uncommented the following line:

```
# make the shell in every window a login shell
shell -$SHELL
```

Answer (score 2):

`screen` opens a new, independent *shell*.

If you want your prompts, aliases, environment variables and such, you will need to copy them over the `.screenrc` file from your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`

For more info, you can refer to the [man page](https://ss64.com/bash/screen.html) (`man screen`) or the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Customization)